# Bad Response error while calling a solidity contract function from getServerSideProps() -next.js

Tags: next.js, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import factory from "../ethereum/factory";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

class CampaignIndex extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>campaigns{this.props.campaigns}</div>;
  }
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const campaigns = await factory.getDeployedCampaigns();
  await campaigns.wait();
  console.log(campaigns);
  return { campaigns };
}

export default CampaignIndex;
```

-> **factory** is an instance of deployed contract 
-> **getDeployedCampaigns()** is a function in deployed contracts which returns an array of addresses 
-> used **Next.js v12.3.1**

When I call **getDeployedCampaigns()** from **getServerSideProps()** block, it returns an error - *bad request*, but if I call above function from elsewhere - except that block, I am getting expected results. I don't know why **next.js** is behaving this way.

Answer (score 0):

*getServerSideProps* runs on the server side at request time. Hence in this case the smart contract has to be instantiated inside the *getServerSideProps* function.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
     const URL = "Provider URL";
     let customHttpProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(URL);

     const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        <Contract address>,
        <ABI>,
        customHttpProvider
     );
     return { props: { data: JSON.stringify(await contract.getDeployedCampaigns()) } 
};
```

*getServerSideProps* has to always return JSON serializable data types. If *getDeployedCampaigns()* is returning JSON serializable data type then no need to write JSON.stringify()